# Is my proof for this claim correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

This has to be proven or disproven using a counter example:

Let $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\frac { p }{ q }$ is irrational.

$p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ $\Rightarrow p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p,q\notin\mathbb{Q}$

Thus $p,q$ are irrational.

If $p=q=\sqrt { 2 } $, then $p,q$ are irrational, but $\frac { p }{ q } =\frac { \sqrt { 2 }  }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } =1$, which is rational.

Comment: So as you noticed, the statement is wrong. You can have $p,q$ irrational and $\frac{p}{q}$ rational. And your counterexample is good.

Comment: I edited my original post. Sorry, I accidentally omitted one of the most important parts.

Comment: Your counter example is good and correct.  For style points, don't do the first bit abut p,q in R\Q.  You aren't selecting arbitrary irrationals, so there is no need to state it here.  when you let p,q = root two, stating that root 2 is irrational is enough.  But that is just me being fussy.

Comment: Now you believe? :)

Comment: @GudsonChou Yes I do :)

Comment: In fact there is nothing mysterious in giving a counterexample...

Comment: Just in case you are not fully aware: be prevented from "memorizing" the form; just try to think over it yourself, and I believe you will come up with something similar.